# Extract search functionality to Form Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application I have simple search functionality. I want to extract  to Form Object but don't know how to do. I have search form which looks like this:

```
.row
  = horizontal_simple_form_for :cars, {url: cars_path, method: :get} do |f|
    .col-md-4
      .row
        .col-md-12
          = f.input :handover_location, label: I18n.t('.handover'), collection: Location.all.map{|hl| [hl.location_address, hl.id]}
          = f.input :return_location, label: I18n.t('.return') ,collection: Location.all.map{|rl| [rl.location_address, rl.id]}
      = f.input :car_class, label: I18n.t('.car_class') ,collection: CarClass.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true
    .col-md-4  
      = f.input :handover_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.input :return_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.submit class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Cars controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check

  def index
    @cars = Car.search(params)
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

And class method in Car model which search correct cars:

```
 def self.search(params) 
    self.joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", 
        params[:cars][:return_date], params[:cars][:handover_date]).
        joins(:car_class).where("car_classes.id= ?", params[:cars][:car_class])
        .cars_at_both_locations(params[:cars][:handover_location], params[:cars][:return_location])
  end
```

Now I'm trying to extract this to Form Object. I've created a file search_form.rb:

```
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :handover_date, :return_date, :handover_location, :return_location, :car_class
end
```

But now I don't know how to handle my params to this form object. Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could help you with the `Form Object` stuff, but I need to learn more about `classes & modules`

---

I *can* help you with the search functionality, as we've done it before [here](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk/)

[image]

Here's the code we used:

```
#View
<%= form_tag search_path, :method => :post, :id => "SearchForm" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Search your favourite products or brands', :autocomplete => :off  %> 
    <%= image_submit_tag 'nav_bar/search.png' %>
<% end %>   

#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'products#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def search
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js     { render :partial => "elements/livesearch", :locals => {:search => @products, :query => params[:search]} }
        format.html   {  render :index }
    end
end
```

---

Notice the [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) we used?

[Simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) does not work with `form_tag` currently (it requires an object) - we just send the data with a `GET` request to the controller & that then sends the data to the `Product` model

I think your problem will be caused by the use of your `SearchForm` object. You only need this because your use of `simple form` means you have to pass an object. Problem being this is not necessary for search

A better way will be to use a standard `form_tag`, and send the request directly to your controller. This will allow you to process the data as `params`, which you'll be able to send directly to your `Car` model

--

I can write some code specific to you if you want

Comment: Thank's for help. I need form object because this search will be in future more advanced and I will need stuff like validations etc. I know that I can do this by form_tag but in my situation it's not a solution.

Comment: Np - the validations being handled by `Car` model?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to validate what user type in search form and second I want to learn form objects :)

Comment: lol okay, that makes two of us! Can you let me know any resources you're using?

Comment: @MateuszUrbański What `form object` are you talking?

Comment: Hmm,It makes the count to three including me :D

Comment: Ok, so does anyone can help me with my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution on my own.
Cars controller:

```
  def index
    @search_form = SearchForm.new(params[:search_form])
    @cars = @search_form.submit(params[:search_form])
  end
```

search_form.rb:

```
class SearchForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :handover_date, :return_date, :handover_location, :return_location, :car_class

  def submit(params)
    Car.search(params)
  end
end
```

Search form in view:

```
.row
  = horizontal_simple_form_for SearchForm.new, {url: cars_path, method: :get} do |f|
    .col-md-4
      .row
        .col-md-12
          = f.input :handover_location, label: I18n.t('.handover'), collection: Location.all.map{|hl| [hl.name, hl.id]}
          = f.input :return_location, label: I18n.t('.return') ,collection: Location.all.map{|rl| [rl.name, rl.id]}
      = f.input :car_class, label: I18n.t('.car_class') ,collection: CarClass.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, include_blank: true
    .col-md-4  
      = f.input :handover_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.input :return_date, as: :string, label: false
      = f.submit class: 'btn btn-success'
```

search method in car model:

```
def self.search(params) 
    self.joins(:reservations).where.not("reservations.reception_time <= ? AND reservations.return_time >= ?", 
        params[:return_date], params[:handover_date]).
        joins(:car_class).where("car_classes.id= ?", params[:car_class])
        .cars_at_both_locations(params[:handover_location], params[:return_location])
  end
```